# client not reading Int flushed using ChannelHandlerContext#writeAndFlush(java.lang.Object)

Tags: netty

Client is not reading Int written by server using ChannelHandlerContext#writeAndFlush(java.lang.Object). In fact, client's io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler#channelRead0 is not executing.

However, when server writes ByteBuf using ChannelHandlerContext#writeAndFlush(java.lang.Object), client reads data as expected.

**Client code:**

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) {
    final ByteBuf buffer = Unpooled.buffer();
    final ByteBuf bytes = in.getBytes(in.readerIndex(), buffer);
    System.out.println("Client received: " + bytes.getInt(bytes.readerIndex()) + "   " + bytes.readableBytes());
}
```

**Non working server code:**

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(100)
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
```

**Working server code (in scala):**

```
val buf = Unpooled.buffer()
buf.writeInt(length)
ctx.writeAndFlush(buf)
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
```

Please help me understand the difference.

Thanks,
Prateek

Answer (score 0):

By default, communications between client and server in Netty are done with `ByteBuf` object. In order to send different kinds of object, we will need `Decoder` and `Encoder`.

Going back to your question, without an appropriate Encoder (in server) and Decoder (in client) in your pipeline, the `Integer` object will not be recognized. In order to make it work, you can try to do the below steps:

1. Add the `ObjectEncoder` into server pipeline (e.g. to encode outgoing `Integer` object.
2. Add the `ObjectDecoder` into client pipeline `ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers                             .cacheDisabled(getClass().getClassLoader()))` (e.g. to decode incoming `Integer` object.
3. Add respective `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Integer>` handler to process message.

Above approach is for your testing only. For production implementation, the message format contract between client and server must be clearly defined. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing something into channel you need to `encode` object to the wire format and after reading from channel you need to covert it back (`decode`) to appropriate object. To make your life easy netty has two classes for writing and reading objects. They are `ObjectEncoder` and `ObjectDecoder`.

You can pass following code to your `Bootstrap.hander()` method of server/client and write your business logic in `YourBusinessLogicHandler` class.

```
new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

                pipeline.addLast(new ObjectEncoder());
                pipeline.addLast(new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)));
                pipeline.addLast(new YourBusinessLogicHandler())
            }
}
```

Client:

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object o) {
    int number = (Integer) o;
    System.out.println("Client received: " + number);
}
```

Server:

```
Integer number = 100;
ctx.writeAndFlush(number);
```

Read this excellent [getting started article](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html) from Netty. It will walk you through all the basics.